# PHP mysqli condition greater than or less than symbol error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the following strange issue in mysqli prepared statement

This is my sample query and params

```
SELECT * from ecf_request WHERE id > ? OR id < ?
...
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $id1); //5, 10
```

When i use just `=` conditions it's working fine but for `>` and `<` conditions it's not working. 
I am getting `"Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement"` error

Is it possible to use greater than and less than symbols in prepared statements ?

I need to implement it for date filter condition. records between two dates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using BETWEEN rather than > and <

Comment: Thanks Mark, but whether greater than and less than symbols are not alloewd in prepared statements. just i try to know

Comment: If you're trying to filter a DATETIME field you might have to bind parameters as "s" instead of "i" [$stmt->bind_param("ss",$var1,$var2);]. FYI you had your condition right in the first place, the OR you have now won't work.

Comment: Thanks to all, after refer all the comments i have modified my query as "SELECT * from ecf_request WHERE date_created BETWEEN ? AND ? " and set the param as  "$stmt->bind_param("ss",$var1,$var2)". it's working fine now. again thanks to all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one `id` cannot be greater and smaller to itself at the same time.
you are giving a condition like `id >10` and `id <10` at the same time.

If you want both id1 and id2 to be selected use `SELECT * from ecf_request WHERE id IN(?,?)` instead of `AND` and if you want to select everything in between then use `SELECT * from ecf_request WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ?`

Comment: Thanks HussainNagri, i have updated my question by OR. but my problem is i want to use date filter in a query. need to take records between two dates. so that i am trying to form my query by > and < symbols. I am ok with IN and BETWEEN methods, but trying to know whats wrong with > and < symbols

Comment: As I told you already one ID cannot be Greater and Smaller at the same time. suppose your current id value is 10 and you are you want to compare it between 7 and 14 then according to your query it will be like "SELECT * from ecf_request WHERE 10 > 7 OR 10 < 14." see it yourself can both the condition be true at the same time ?

Comment: OP's original WHERE clause was an almost-precise translation of a BETWEEN clause (with the exception of equality) and was in fact a correct way of ranging a parameter

Comment: @Alex you mean this " SELECT * from ecf_request WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ? " wont work for all the id's in between including upper and lower limit ?

Comment: I don't get it : in `WHERE 10 > 7 OR 10 < 14` both conditions *are* true.  In fact, you can replace `10` with any number and the whole WHERE clause would be true no matter what. I might be missing something but this post and the follow-up comment just don't make any sense to me. `BETWEEN this AND that` is not wrong but contradicts everything else written above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BETWEEN statement. Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM `ecf_request` WHERE `id` BETWEEN ? AND ?
```