# PHP MySQLi prepared statements select rows that are added to records in specific time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, microtime

I'm having a similar error: [PHP mysqli condition greater than or less than symbol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607434/php-mysqli-condition-greater-than-or-less-than-symbol-error)

But I don't find a solution to this since my application is a bit different.

I have following statement right now:

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM applications");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $MTNOW);
```

Everytime my users sends a new application there will be a field named "mtime" which stands "microtime" and it's rounded to numeric format without a double value so it's 1489344810.

How do I can make a calculation to prepared statement like that it will select each row's microtime and increase it by 18000 seconds (5 hours) so I can compare the result to current microtime? It should show only results that are created in 5 hours. Rest of the records will not be shown.

The idea:

```
SELECT * FROM applications WHERE (mtime+18000) < ?
bind_param("i", $MTNOW);
```

Comment: you didn't bind (no placeholder) anything in your select and you expect that to work? Go and RTM on that.

Comment: You're right. I didn't, because I cleared my attempts. Sorry if it made you confused. Anyways the statement below the other didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM applications WHERE mtime < ?");
$stmt->bind_param("1", (yourValue + or - 18000));
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```